# Does converting a foreign company's profit to US dollars change the PE ratio?

Tags: stocks, investing

When calculating the PE ratio of a company that reports in EUR, would the EPS be converted at today's exchange rate or the rate on the latest fiscal period end date (i.e. Dec 31, 2021)?

Answer (score 2):

You should be comparing apples to apples. So if you're converting the share price at today's exchange rate, you should convert the earnings at today's exchange rate.

Comment: Thanks so much!